# Как произвести сравнение двух столбцов js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите условие которое сравнивало бы два слова в двух столбцах. Например Если позиция (опоздание более 15 мин = согласовано то счетчик прибавлял бы +1 ну или на js k++) если (опоздание менее 15 мин и не согласовано то ни чего бы не происходило.)

У меня на данный момент есть функция которая считает значения в столбце. Но вот как сравнить два слова в разных столбцах не могу придумать.

```
var bol = 0;
var min=0;

$('td:nth-child(8)').each(function() {
   if($(this).text() == 'опоздание БОЛЕЕ 15min') {
      bol++;
   }
   if($(this).text() == 'опоздание МЕНЕЕ 15min') {
      min++;
   }
});

$('span.bol').text('' + bol);
$('span.min').text('' + min);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте оператор `&&`

```
$('tr').each(function (row) {
    var col1 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    var col2 = $(row).children('td:nth-child(2)').text();
    if (col1 === 'опоздание БОЛЕЕ 15min' &&  col2 === 'согласовано') {
        k++;
    }
});
```